# Rings not displaying on .TAB import to .SHP save

Tags: qgis, editing, import

I have some strange behaviour happening when importing a MapInfo .TAB file into QGIS. One feature contains internal rings which are ok on initial import but do not show on the first .SHP save. I can see the ring perimeter but selecting picks the feature as a whole, shading in the ring areas. It's only if I save again that they appear properly cutout and all appears ok.

I've used the MapInfo file with Manifold and no issues in that software. However saving the file as a .MIF in Manifold and importing into QGIS I lose the rings in the initial import and again need to save twice to .SHP to get them to appear ok.

Just wondered if anyone had an explanation?

Comment: If you have access to [FME](http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/) you should use that for converting between the types.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Have used FME at last company and a great tool but have no access to it now. I was going to look at GeoKettle which is an open-source ETL tool similiar to FME. However I assume this is pretty basic stuff (famous last words). Doesn't cause an issue just a duplicate button push....

Comment: GeoKettle is not the solution for this issue. FME give you choice between MFAL writer and MITAB writer. The first is official MapInfo Tab format the last is open source. The MITAB can suffer from weird topology errors, so maybe your .TAB was created with MITAB

Comment: The .TAB was created using MapInfo 12 so is a true MapInfo file. The comment on GeoKettle was an aside as I didn't think I would need to use something as specialised as FME to get the file to display correctly first time in QGIS. It displays but just takes 2 saves to a .SHP to do it properly (specifically for the enclosed polygons). Just like to know why it does it.